# DAX Calculation for the last 180 days

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm wanting to perform a calcualtion that returns the rolling deviation from the mean for the last 180 days. I want all the previous data to be visible however the calculation to simply include the previous 180 days.

This the code I have:

```
AVEDEV 180D = 
VAR prev180 = 
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
        'Table'[Date] <=MAX('Table'[Date])
           
        
    )
VAR mean = 
    AVERAGEX(
        prev180,
        ChangeQtyChangeQtyType[Fail Rate 2]
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX(
            prev180,
            ABS([Fail Rate 2] - mean)
        ),
        COUNTROWS(prev180)
    )
```

But the calculation is for all entries. I'm hoping it's just a simple adjustment to the filter function?

Comment: I presume `ChangeQtyChangeQtyType[Fail Rate 2]` and `[Fail Rate 2]` are one and the same? And what's the relationship between the `ChangeQtyChangeQtyType` and `Table` tables?

Comment: Hi Jos, yes they're the same.  Also, I've added an image to highlight the relationships between the tables.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure I understand your current definition for `prev180`. How is that supposed to filter for the past 180 days only?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't, I'm wanting to perform a calculation for the previous 180 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=
VAR First_Date =
    TODAY() - 180
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DIVIDE(
            SUMX(
                ChangeQtyChangeQtyType,
                ABS(
                    [Fail Rate 2]
                        - AVERAGEX(
                            ChangeQtyChangeQtyType,
                            ChangeQtyChangeQtyType[Fail Rate 2]
                        )
                )
            ),
            COUNTROWS( ChangeQtyChangeQtyType )
        ),
        'Table'[Date] >= First_Date
    )
```